# Automatic zooming into my location after opening the app like uber,ola,Gmap

Tags: android, google-maps, location

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohvf1.png)
Now I have to click location button in my app to get view of my on location but I want the view similar like Uber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the camera to you current Location, and animate it for smooth zooming to your location:

```
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(your_location, 15));
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);
```